# Generating set of $\mathcal{Q}_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quaternions, finitely-generated

The definition of a generating set $S$ of a subgroup $H\leq G$ is such that if $S$ is a subset of $H$, then for any subgroup $K\le G$ containing $S$, $H\leq K$. Now, for $\mathcal{Q}_8$, if $S=\{i, j\}$ then $\mathcal{Q}_8$ is not a proper subgroup of any group. So I'm not sure how to build this proof based on the definition.

I would appreciate some hints.

Comment: "there is no such group whose subgroup is Q8" - can you clarify this?

Comment: There does not exist a group $H$ such that $\mathcal{Q}_8 \leq H$.

Comment: Yes there does: $H = \mathcal{Q}_8$ itself!  And of course it's the only one.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a proper subgroup.

Comment: Another wording could be: "$\ldots$ then there is no such group having $\mathcal Q_8$ as a proper subgroup."

Comment: The issue is that I don't know how to build a proof based on the definition.

Comment: But the definition of generating set does not say proper subgroup; it only says subgroup ($\le$).  Apply the definition with $S=\{i,j\}$, $H=Q_8$, $G = Q_8$.

Comment: I've thought about it. But then what do we get? Given that $G= \mathcal{Q}_8$ and $H=\mathcal{Q}_8$, $H$ contains $S$, and thus $\mathcal{Q}_8$ contains $S$ and $\mathcal{Q}_8\leq \mathcal{Q}_8$. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Every group contains itself as a subgroup. Sometimes a generating set generates the whole group and *only* the whole group. This is true for any trivial group $G = \{e\}$ and any generating set (there are only two such sets); it is also true for any cyclic group and the singleton set containing just the/a generator.

Comment: Yes, but how does one prove that $\{i, j\}$ is a set generating $\mathcal{Q}_8$?